# Rails 4 - order by translated / localized value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, localization

I have a table called `items` with a `type` column. 
This column can have one of the following values:

```
rock
paper
scissor
```

Inside my translation file:

```
en: 
  rock: Stone
  paper: Wood
  scissor: Weapon
```

How can i fetch the results and order them by the translated value using ActiveRecord?

Obviously, if I do `Item.where(something: true).order('name asc')` I would get the results ordered by the value inside the database (`rock`) and not the translated value (`Stone`).

I am aware of some ruby methods such as `sort_by` and `sort` to order items with ruby, but I would like to order the results in ActiveRecord for performance reasons.

Comment: How many unique types are there?  If the list is relatively short you could build up an `order` statement to do this.  MySQL has a [FIELD() method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/396771/2622934) and in Postgres you could build a [case statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1310188/2622934).

Comment: @cschroed there are only 3 types (rock, paper, scissor)

Comment: @cschroed do you know how to solve this without knowing how many types there are?

Comment: A generic version of your answer would be something like `translation = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"].map{ |name| "WHEN type = '#{name}' THEN '#{I18n.t(name)}'" }.join(" "); Item.select("*, CASE #{translation} END AS translated_type").order("translated_type")`.  But with a really huge list this might break the limits on how many `WHEN` entries are allowed in a query.

Comment: @cschroed yeah, I also thought of that but the other list consists of nearly 740 items. So much for looping through a list!

Comment: If ordering at the database level is really important you could potentially store those translations in a table that you can join with and order by.

Comment: @cschroed So a seperate table for each language in the app?

Comment: Right.  Or a table that can group these special strings by language.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9890245/2622934) has additional suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using a `CASE` statement.

```
Item.select("*,
  CASE 
    WHEN type = 'rock' THEN '#{I18n.t(:rock)}' 
    WHEN type = 'paper' THEN '#{I18n.t(:paper)}' 
    WHEN type = 'scissor' THEN '#{I18n.t(:scissor)}'
  END AS translated_type
")
.where(something: true)
.order('translated_type asc')
```

This works fine in my case since I know which types to expect.