# PostgreSQL: performance impact of extra columns

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql

Given a large table (10-100 million rows) what's the best way to add some extra (unindexed) columns to it?

1. Just add the columns.
2. Create a separate table for each extra column, and use joins when you want to access the extra values.

Does the answer change depending on whether the extra columns are dense (mostly not null) or sparse (mostly null)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A column with a `NULL` value can be added to a row without any changes to the rest of the data page [*in most cases*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7383198/939860). Only one bit has to be set in the **NULL bitmap**. So, yes, a sparse column is much cheaper to add in most cases.

Whether it is a good idea to create a **separate 1:1 table for additional columns** very much depends on the use case. It is generally more expensive. For starters, there is an overhead of 28 bytes (heap tuple header plus item identifier) per row and some additional overhead per table. It is also much more expensive to `JOIN` rows in a query than to read them in one piece. And you need to add a primary / foreign key column plus an index on it. Splitting may be a good idea if you don't need the additional columns in most queries. Mostly it is a bad idea.

Adding a column is fast in PostgreSQL. **Updating** the values in the column is what may be expensive, because every `UPDATE` writes a new row (due to the [MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html) model). Therefore, it is a good idea to update multiple columns at once.

[Database page layout in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html)

How to calculate row sizes:

- [Making sense of Postgres row sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570613/making-sense-of-postgres-row-sizes/13570853#13570853)
- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468)

Comment: `there is an overhead of 28 bytes (heaptuple header plus item pointer) per row and some additional overhead per table` Just to confirm, does this mean that a through-table with three 4-byte integers (primary key + 2 foreign keys) would take 28+12 bytes per row?

Comment: @DavidTan: Actually, a total of 44 bytes per row. 24 + 4 + 3*4 + 4 bytes of alignment padding. I added links to more detailed explanation above.