# How many records can I store in 5 MB of PostgreSQL on Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, heroku, storage

I'm going to store records in a single table with 2 fields:

- id -> 4 characters
- password_hash -> 64 characters

How many records like the one above will I be able to store in a 5mb PostgreSQL on Heroku?

P.S.: given a single table with x columns and a length of y - how can I calculate the space it will take in a database?

Comment: Are you going to insert the rows into database, or do you want to update/delete them as well?

Comment: how does this affects space occupied? anyway i don't think updates but delete operations probably yes

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi: Updating / Deleting leaves dead rows that occupy space that only `VACUUM` or `CLUSTER` can recover.

Comment: Also keep in mind, 5mb is a "soft" limit. You can go beyond that. Once you start pushing 50mb, they will ask you to upgrade.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

#### Disk space occupied

Calculating the space on disk is not trivial. You have to take into account:

- The **overhead per table**. Small, basically the entries in the system catalog.
- The **overhead per row** (`HeapTupleHeader`) and per data page (`PageHeaderData`). Details about [page layout in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html).
- Space lost to [**column alignment**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860), depending on data types.
- Space for a [**NULL bitmap**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7383198/939860). Effectively free for tables of 8 columns or less, irrelevant for your case.
- **Dead rows** after `UPDATE` / `DELETE`. (Until the space is eventually vacuumed and reused.)
- Size of **index(es)**. You'll have a primary key, right? Index size is similar to that of a table with just the indexed columns and less overhead per row.
- The actual space requirement of the data, depending on respective **data types**. [Details for character types (incl. fixed length types) in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html):

  > The storage requirement for a short string (up to 126 bytes) is 1 byte
  > plus the actual string, which includes the space padding in the case
  > of `character`. Longer strings have 4 bytes of overhead instead of 1

  More details for all types in the system catalog [`pg_type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html).
- The database **encoding** in particular for character types. UTF-8 uses up to four bytes to store one character (But 7-Bit-ASCII characters always occupy just one byte, even in UTF-8.)
- Other small things that may affect your case, like [**TOAST**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html) - which should not affect you with 64-character strings.

#### Calculate with test case

A simple method to find an estimate is to create a test table, fill it with dummy data and measure with [database object size functions:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE):

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('tbl'));
```

Including indexes:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('tbl'));
```

See:

- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23933/3684)

A quick test shows the following results:

```
CREATE TABLE test(a text, b text);
INSERT INTO test -- quick fake of matching rows
SELECT chr((g/1000 +32)) || to_char(g%1000, 'FM000')
     , repeat (chr(g%120 + 32), 64)
FROM   generate_series(1,50000) g;

SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('test'));       -- 5640 kB
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('test')); -- 5648 kB
```

After adding a primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY(a);

SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('test')); -- 6760 kB
```

So, I'd expect a maximum of around **44k** rows without and around **36k** rows with primary key.