# Dropping column in Postgres on a large dataset

Tags: postgresql, database-design, ddl, database-performance, postgresql-9.2

So I have a table with a large dataset and this table has a three columns that I would like to drop.
The question is: how will Postgres deal with it?

Will it walk through every entry or will it just update mapping info without much overhead?
Can I just make an `ALTER TABLE` or should I use swap-table in this particular case?

And, if it makes any difference, all three columns have fixed length (two integers and one numeric).

I'm sorry if it's been asked already, but Google couldn't find any related questions / articles ...

Answer (score 79, accepted):

ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN does just only disabling columns in system tables. It is very fast, but it doesn't remove data from heap files. You have to do VACUUM FULL later to compact allocated file space. So ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN is very fast. And to compact files, you have to call the slower (with exclusive LOCK) VACUUM FULL.

Answer (score 72):

Google may have been useless for this question, but [the manual rarely fails](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-NOTES):

> The `DROP COLUMN` form does not physically remove the column, but
> simply makes it invisible to SQL operations. Subsequent insert and
> update operations in the table will store a null value for the column.
> Thus, dropping a column is quick but it will not immediately reduce
> the on-disk size of your table, as the space occupied by the dropped
> column is not reclaimed. The space will be reclaimed over time as
> existing rows are updated.

And:

> To force an immediate rewrite of the table, you can use `VACUUM FULL`,
> `CLUSTER` or one of the forms of `ALTER TABLE` that forces a rewrite.
> This results in no semantically-visible change in the table, but gets
> rid of no-longer-useful data.

Specifically, the column `attisdropped` in the system catalog table [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) is set to `true`.

#### Side effects

There are minor side-effects (as [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1576886/chris-cogdon) pointed out):

- Updated or newly inserted rows still store an invisible null value which forces a null bitmap for every new row, even with no null in visible columns. Does *not* affect existing rows as those keep the original (now invisible) column value.
- The null bitmap must be big enough to cover all visible *and* dropped columns. In corner cases it may be enlarged by this. About effective size:

  - [Do nullable columns occupy additional space in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145772/do-nullable-columns-occupy-additional-space-in-postgresql/12147130#12147130)
- Dropped columns count against the allowed maximum (which you shouldn't be scraping anyway).
- There is currently (Postgres 16) no easy way to get rid of the zombi column completely. The above mentioned table rewrites replace invisible values with `null`, which reclaims *almost* all space but doesn't purge the dropped column from the system catalogs. Not even `TRUNCATE` does. Only creating a new table or a dump/restore cycle does that.

Comment: Interestingly, because row updates will now "store" NULLs in the dropped columns. And because postgresql stores nulls by setting a bit in the optional "null bitmap", _every_ row must now have a null bitmap (of a size of one byte for every eight dropped or non-dropped column) even if none of the visible rows are NULL