# postgresql copy few csv columns to specific column on my table

Tags: postgresql, csv

i used postgresql copy to store my csv file to my table. But the thing is on my csv table i have 4field

```
f2 f5 f6 f13
```

and on my postgresql table have 8 table

```
f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8
```

and i want to make f1 the sequence i make, and f3 is current_date and the other is null

this is similiar to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618232/copy-a-few-of-the-columns-of-a-csv-file-into-a-table), but that question is asked on 2013 (maybe now there is other solution?)

The point is i want to insert from specific column from csv to specific column postgresql, if possible i dont want to make temporary table

Answer (score 0):

You can selectively declare target columns with [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html):

```
COPY tbl(f2, f5, f6, f7) FROM '/path/to/file.csv'
```

If the source file has columns you do *not* want to insert into the table at all, you *need* another (temporary) table as stepping stone - `COPY` to it and `INSERT` from there. Or you edit the input file to remove the excess column.

---

Another option would be to add a column to the target table temporarily. Adding a NULL column is cheap and does not trigger a table rewrite. You can `COPY` to the table and then drop the column again. This, too, does not trigger a table rewrite and is also very cheap: the dropped column is still physically there, but is marked dead in the system catalog `pg_attribute`. Any `UPDATE` on a row or `VACUUM FULL` on the table or a backup/restore cycle will remove the dead column physically.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN f13 text;
COPY tbl(f2, f5, f6, f13) FROM '/path/to/file.csv'
ALTER TABLE tbl DROP COLUMN f13;
```

If you do it all within a single transaction, the column remains invisible to the rest of the world.

**However**:

- only the *owner* of the table (and superusers) can use `ALTER TABLE`.
- dropped columns are currently (Postgres 12) kept as invisible zombis in the system catalogs, which can have some minor side effects. See:

  - [Dropping column in Postgres on a large dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699989/dropping-column-in-postgres-on-a-large-dataset/15700213#15700213)

Related:

- [How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres/8910810#8910810)

Comment: f13 is data that i dont need to put into database

Comment: @AlexanderChandra: I added one more idea.