# How can I prevent dropped columns contributing to column limit?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm adding one column in table and after that I'm dropping it too.  I found that dropping the column will just hide but not remove it.

Because I repeatedly add and remove columns, I soon get  this error:

> ERROR:  tables can have at most 1600 columns

I know that one solution is to drop the table and recreate it, but it will incur overhead, so it's not suitable for my situation.

How else can I avoid this error?

Comment: Dropping a column will not actual be removed. You should do VACUUM and then ANALYZE on the table to remove it permanently

Comment: yes I have done that Thanks.But still it will be costly operation right ?

Comment: Yes, it is a costly operation and that's why it better to do that once a day. If DML operations are happening more on a table then its better to do VACUUM and ANALYZE at least once a day. It will be useful for the query plan to build a better plan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropping column in Postgres on a large dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699989/dropping-column-in-postgres-on-a-large-dataset)

Comment: A duplicated questions, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699989/dropping-column-in-postgres-on-a-large-dataset, Pavel Stehule's answer is good there.

Comment: Perhaps the temporarily added column should not be part of the table, but instead on a temporary table that can be joined on this table's primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping a column will not actual be removed. You should do VACUUM and then ANALYZE on the table to remove it permanently.

It is a costly operation and that's why it better to do that once a day. If DML operations are happening more on a table then its better to do VACUUM and ANALYZE at least once a day. It will be useful for the query plan to build a better plan

Comment: * `VACUUM FULL`, not a regular `VACUUM`. Also, `ANALYZE` can be included to this single command: `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE;`. And to see more details: `VACUUM FULL VERBOSE ANALYZE;`.

Comment: Also, remarks on doing `VACUUM` "once per day" are not really relevant -- there is a special process, `autovacuum`, which makes it (both `VACUUM` and `ANALYZE`) for you automatically. And regular `VACUUM` is not that heavy operation, unlike `VACUUM FULL`, which physically reorganizes the table.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: `VACUUM FULL` reclaims the space used by a dropped column, but it does **not** remove the column definition; see here: http://rextester.com/UXIN10960 . As far as I know, recreating the table (either manually, or via `pg_dump` & restore) is the only way to reset this 1600-column limit.