# With a foreign composite key, it possible to reference a column and a fixed value?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

Following is my use case:

I have 4 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
  name character(20) NOT NULL,
  id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE B
(
  name character(20) NOT NULL,
  id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT b_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE C
(
  name character(20) NOT NULL,
  id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT c_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE X
(
  type character(20) NOT NULL,
  other_id integer NOT NULL,
  id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "X_PK" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

the "other_id" in the table X can be the "id" of any of the table A, B or C. The "type" column in table X is suppose to be indicating which of the tables A,B or C "id" is stored in in "other_id"

example data from table x:

```
type  other_id  id
"A"    1         1
"B"    1         2
"C"    1         3
"A"    2         4
```

Trying to create composite FKs between table X-A, X-B and X-C as follows using a fixed value

```
ALTER TABLE x
ADD CONSTRAINT X_A_FK FOREIGN KEY (other_id, type) REFERENCES a (id, 'A') ON DELETE CASCADE
```

but I get this error (same problem for all the FKs):

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "'A'"

My question is, with a foreign composite key, it possible to reference a column and a fixed value? If not What would be a better way of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest an alternative design:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  a_id integer PRIMARY KEY -- pk is NOT NULL automatically
 ,a    text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE b ( ...);
CREATE TABLE c ( ...);

CREATE TABLE x (
  x_id integer PRIMARY KEY        -- or maybe a serial?
 ,a_id integer REFERENCES a(a_id) -- can be NULL
 ,b_id integer REFERENCES b(b_id)
 ,c_id integer REFERENCES c(c_id)
);
```

The major point is to have three columns (`a_id, b_id, c_id`) instead of two in your design (`other_id, type`). Contrary to what one might think, this needs ***less*** disk space, while being cleaner and simpler. You don't need additional constraints or indices to enforce referential integrity.
[`NULL` storage is cheap.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145772/does-null-occupy-space-in-postgresql/12147130#12147130)

**If** you want to enforce, that **at most one** of (`a, b, c`) can be linked at a time, add a [**`CHECK` constraint**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS):

```
ALTER TABLE x ADD CONSTRAINT x_max1_fk
CHECK (a_id IS NULL AND b_id IS NULL
    OR b_id IS NULL AND c_id IS NULL
    OR a_id IS NULL AND c_id IS NULL)
```

Seems lengthy, but is very cheap and simple.

**If** you want to enforce that **exactly one** of (`a, b, c`) must be linked at a time, modify to:

```
ALTER TABLE x ADD CONSTRAINT x_exactly1_fk
CHECK (a_id IS NULL AND b_id IS NULL AND c_id IS NOT NULL
    OR b_id IS NULL AND c_id IS NULL AND a_id IS NOT NULL
    OR a_id IS NULL AND c_id IS NULL AND b_id IS NOT NULL)
```

For **more than just a few columns** I would use:

```
ALTER TABLE x ADD CONSTRAINT x_exactly1_fk
CHECK ((a_id IS NULL)::int
     + (b_id IS NULL)::int
     + (c_id IS NULL)::int = 1)  -- or <= 1 for the former case
```

Note how I avoid the column names `id` and `name`. Use descriptive names instead, this makes your life easier when joining a couple of tables - which you will have to do a lot with a design like this and which is what you *do* in a relational database.

And I use `text` instead of `varchar(20)`. [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings)

I would also consider the [`ON UPDATE CASCADE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) and possibly `ON DELETE CASCADE` modifiers for the foreign keys.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I was considering adding extra null-able columns but was not sure if that is a good practice, because if there will be more tables such as A, B and C in the future, I will need to make more null-able columns. I do appreciate your CHECK suggestions, very handy and clean for insuring the data integrity.

Comment: @IdaN: If you have dozens of referenced tables and only a single one of them applies, `(id, type)` becomes more favorable. I would ask the question, though, whether you couldn't bundle your referenced tables into one (intermediary) table or use [inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html) ...

Comment: In my case I only have few tables and your current solution perfectly applies. I only asked the question to know your opinion on what would be a better approach on a much larger case than couple of tables.

Answer (score 0):

Per the error you're getting, it's not possible. But you've at least two options to achieve the same:

1. You could add a `check` constraint on `type` and enforce a foreign key on `(other_id)` or `(other_id, type)` instead.
2. You could add constraint triggers that enforces the pseudo-foreign key directly.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, would you please elaborate a little bit more on your first solution, I am not sure how to implement it. I probably should add I needed 3 Fks, I only mentioned one in my question because the very first one I tried to make, failed.