# Does setting column default values hurt in terms of DB space?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

This is a quick question. I was curious as to whether setting the default value for a column in Rails+PostgreSQL costs additional space (versus leaving the default as nil).

I am also curious if that naturally leads to concluding whether creating an empty record using rails (full of nils) takes the same space as a row full of data would.

I would suppose this highly depends on the DB implementation, but I am only interested in PostgreSQL databases (9.1+). But I got lost when I was searching for implementation details specific to that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do nullable columns occupy additional space in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145772/do-nullable-columns-occupy-additional-space-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the default is just an attribute in the the catalog table `pg_attributes`.

But actual values in table rows generally cost additional disk space as compared to `NULL`. `NULL` values are stored in a special structure called "NULL bitmap", and require a single bit per column. Therefore, a row with `NULL` values typically takes less space on disk than a row with (dummy) values.

It's actually more complicated. Find details and links in these related answers:

- [Do nullable columns occupy additional space in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145772/do-nullable-columns-occupy-additional-space-in-postgresql/12147130#12147130)
- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468)