# Change varchar to boolean in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, query-optimization, storage, postgresql-9.1

I've started working on a project where there is a fairly large table (about 82,000,000 rows) that I think is very bloated. One of the fields is defined as:

```
consistency character varying NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y'::character varying
```

It's used as a boolean, the values should always either be ('Y'|'N').

Note: there is no check constraint, etc.

I'm trying to come up with reasons to justify changing this field. Here is what I have:

- It's being used as a boolean, so make it that.  Explicit is better than implicit.
- It will protect against coding errors because right now there anything that can be converted to text will go blindly in there.

Here are my question(s).

- What about size/storage? The db is UTF-8. So, I *think* there really isn't much of a savings in that regard.  It should be 1 byte for a `boolean`, but also 1 byte for a `'Y'` in UTF-8 (at least that's what I get when I check the length in Python). Is there any other storage overhead here that would be saved?
- Query performance?  Will Postgres get any performance gains for a where cause of "`=TRUE`" vs. "`='Y'`"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

PostgreSQL (unlike Oracle) has a fully-fledged [**`boolean`** type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html). Generally, a "yes/no flag" should be `boolean`. That's the appropriate type!

#### What about size/storage?

A [`boolean`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html) column occupies **1 byte** on disk.
([The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)) about `text` or `character varying`:

> the storage requirement for a short string (up to 126 bytes) is 1 byte
> plus the actual string

That's at least **2 bytes** for a single character.

Actual storage is more complicated than that. There is some fixed overhead per table, [page and row](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html), there is special [`NULL` storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7383198/939860) and some types require [data alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860). See:

- [How many records can I store in 5 MB of PostgreSQL on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885706/how-many-records-can-i-store-in-5-mb-of-postgresql-on-heroku/10886041#10886041)

Encoding `UTF8` doesn't make any difference here. Basic ASCII-characters are bit-compatible with other encodings like `LATIN-1`.

In your case, according to your description, you should keep the [`NOT NULL` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#id-1.5.4.6.6) you already have - independent of the data type.

#### Query performance?

Will be slightly better in any case with `boolean`. Besides being smaller, the logic for `boolean` is simpler and `varchar` or `text` are also generally burdened with [`COLLATION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COLLATE-EXPRS) rules. But don't expect much for something that simple.

Instead of:

```
WHERE consistency = 'Y'
```

You *could* write:

```
WHERE consistency = true
```

But rather simplify to just:

```
WHERE consistency
```

No further evaluation needed.

#### Change type

Transforming your table is simple:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER consistency TYPE boolean
USING CASE consistency WHEN 'Y' THEN true ELSE false END;
```

This `CASE` expression folds everything that is not `TRUE` ('Y') to `FALSE`. The `NOT NULL` constraint just stays.

Comment: @DavidS Note that changing the type via `ALTER TABLE` will exclusively lock the whole table while it's rewritten. If you can't afford that you can do it in steps: `ALTER TABLE` to add a new nullable boolean field; `UPDATE` to populate that field; `ALTER TABLE` to make it `NOT NULL`, `ALTER TABLE` to drop the old varchar column and `ALTER TABLE` to rename the new boolean column to the varchar column's name. You can add a trigger that traps new `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s while the rewrite is in progress and makes sure they set the new boolean col too.

Answer (score 3):

Neither storage size nor query performance will be significantly better switching from a single VARCHAR to a BOOLEAN.  Although you are right that it's technically cleaner to use boolean when you are talking about a binary value the cost to change is probably significantly higher than the benefit.  If you're worried about correctness then you could put a check on the column, for example

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT consistency CHECK (consistency IN ('Y', 'N'));
```