# CASE WHEN in request

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a "*user_activity_log*" table that contains the fields "*id*", "*client_id*", "*hitdatetime*", and *"action*".

| id | client_id | hitdatetime | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2661715 | 17 | 2020-09-18 11:30:43 | visit |
| 2661716 | 17 | 2020-09-18 11:30:54 | registration |
| 2661717 | 17 | 2020-09-18 11:31:16 | visit |

It is necessary to output:

- "*client_id*", from the input table
- "*visit_dt*", that is associated to the "*hitdatetime*" field when the "*action*" equals to `'visit'`, otherwise it is null
- "*is_registration*", that is associated to `1` if "*action*" equals to `'registration'`, otherwise it is `0`

The `CASE` statement is mandatory for this query.

I've started writing the query, but I don't know what to put in place of the signs `???`.

```sql
SELECT client_id, 
      CASE WHEN action = 'visit' THEN ???  ELSE 'NULL' END as visit_dt, 
      CASE WHEN action = 'registration' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as is_registration 
FROM  user_activity_log;
```

Can you provide help?

Comment: `hitdatetime` column!!!

Comment: You said you wanted "the value from the hitdatetime field". Did you try writing `hitdatetime`? Did it do what you hoped?

Comment: I started with this. But there was a mistake

Comment: Its probblay you set the null values as string , remove the quotations around null

Comment: Also, be careful that `NULL` and `'NULL'` are different values, make sure you know which one you want.

Comment: `else 'null'` is not needed 1st because if you're using a `case` statement and there's no `else` then when it doesn't find a match it returns `null`. 2nd it's `null` not `'null'`

Comment: Also remove quotes around `0` and `1`

Comment: Thank you all. I just didn't understand the condition initially. There all the values were in quotation marks. When I removed them, everything worked

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following one:

```
SELECT client_id, 
       CASE WHEN action = 'visit' 
            THEN hitdatetime END AS visit_dt, 
       CASE WHEN action = 'registration' 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0           END AS is_registration 
FROM user_activity_log;
```

Side notes:

- if the `ELSE` clause of the `CASE` statement should evaluate to NULL, you are not required to specify it as it is default value
- use numeric values in place of strings if the nature of your input should be numeric
- always prefer using NULL instead of the corresponding `"NULL"` string, as sql provides a whole set of functions that can handle NULL values in a better way

Comment: *as sql provides a whole set of functions that can handle NULL values in a better way* Is not really the reason not to use `'null'`. It's just that `null` is a **non value**, while `'null'` is a string.

Comment: That's a nice description improvement over the third bullet, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

`is_registration` should really be [**`boolean`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html). Also makes the query simpler:

```sql
SELECT client_id
     , CASE WHEN action = 'visit' THEN hitdatetime END AS visit_dt
     , action = 'registration' AS is_registration  -- !
FROM   user_activity_log;
```

If `action` can be NULL, so can be `is_registration`. If you want `false` instead of `null`, use one of these:

```
action IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'registration' AS is_registration
```

Or:

```
COALESCE(action = 'registration', false) AS is_registration
```

Related:

- [Change varchar to boolean in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824317/change-varchar-to-boolean-in-postgresql/12830390#12830390)
- [Why does PostgreSQL not return null values when the condition is <> true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679721/why-does-postgresql-not-return-null-values-when-the-condition-is-true/17680845#17680845)
- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625)