# PostgreSQL: performance of select null vs false

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql

In PostgreSQL (v9.4) with a big table (> 10M rows), is there any difference in the performance (speed) of these two queries?

1. Select all entries with a `null` value in a `bigint` column.
2. Select all entries with a `false` value in a `boolean` column.

Also, would it make any difference if query number 1 was performed on a `varchar` column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No--theoretically, none of your options in and of themselves will produce a performance difference.  You are merely comparing data.  Where there will be a difference is if any of the columns you specify in your WHERE clause is indexed.

Comment: I would add *partial* index might be better if you are not interested in all other *bigint* values. `create index nonnullindex on mytable(mybigint) where mybigint is not null;`

Comment: That's not _strictly_ true: NULLs are stored as a bitmap in the tuple header, and are checked before any other comparison, so theoretically, a NULL check is less work than an equality comparison. Practically, of course, the difference is negligible, since you'll end up reading the same number of pages.

Comment: I see. Thanks everyone for your contributions! One last point to clarify. @Russ, mlt, and Dmitri: is there any difference in the size and indexing overhead of a b-tree index for a boolean column vs a bigint column?