# PostgreSQL: Finding and Dropping null columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Got a bunch of tables with 40 odd columns some with ~60 million rows

Within a table there are a number of columns where every row is null I need to identify these and separate from the not null columns  (where at least 1 row has data).

It's not entirely clear if dropping the null columns will free up disk space but by identifying the null and not null columns will allow easier data filtering e.g. `SELECT id,b,c,d FROM t` or building views etc.

In this example I need to find column a / A

```
create table t (id int, a int, b int, c int, d int);
insert into t (id, a, b, c, d) values
(1, null, 7, 7, 7),
(2, null, 7, 7, null),
(3, null, 7, 7, 7);

 select DISTINCT
   case when a is null then 'A ' else '' end ||
   case when b is null then 'B ' else '' end ||
   case when c is null then 'C ' else '' end ||
   case when d is null then 'D ' else '' end as null_columns
 from t
```

Returns

```
null_columns
A
A D
```

Here's  a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ANMVL9-h)

I need just "A"

Comment: Unlikely that you're going to win anything: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008753/does-not-using-null-in-postgresql-still-use-a-null-bitmap-in-the-header/7383198#7383198

Comment: `SELECT id,b,c,d FROM t` you can do this regardless of whether you drop any columns or not.

Comment: this may help: [query-to-get-counts-of-values-per-column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249726/query-to-get-counts-of-values-per-column)

Comment: To do `SELECT id,b,c,d FROM t` need to work out the nulls also when users connect to the DB via external applications they basically use `SELECT * FROM t` so the user only wants to see the not nulls columns Dropping nulls solves that problem
See https://dbfiddle.uk/Eq7FSiYS For my solution Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropping columns that contain NULL will not free any storage space. Dropping columns never frees storage space in PostgreSQL. But you couldn't save any storage space anyway, since a NULL column does not take up any space in PostgreSQL.

You could find columns with all NULLs by counting:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN count(a) = 0 THEN 'a has only NULLs' END,
       CASE WHEN count(b) = 0 THEN 'b has only NULLs' END,
       ...
FROM t;
```

Comment: Thanx for your help here's an updated fiddle with an solution https://dbfiddle.uk/Eq7FSiYS Three steps 1st build query to create above counts, 2nd run the output 3rd manually check and drop null columns no it won't free up space but what's left is  only columns with data. BtW: This is a slow process count(colName) on 40 columns.