# What's the cost of CHECK constraints in Postgres 9.x?

Tags: sql, postgresql, benchmarking, postgresql-9.1, check-constraints

I have a table with 60 columns. 20 of those are "NotEmpty" and 6  "NotNull".

I have empty values and Null values (which always mean "no data" in my case). I'd like to unify columns with just one type of constraint.

I have read null values are cheap (in byte size). So maybe use NotEmpty constraints? But maybe NotNull constraints perform better? Or maybe it's better to have both values and use `coalesce()` when retrieving data?

What's the cost of `CHECK` constraints for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` in Postgres 9.x? What's about your experience? Any benchmarks?

Comment: Null checks are a bit faster (there's a flag in the catalog) but you almost certainly have more important things to be worrying about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some people try to avoid `NULL` values, claiming the logic would be confusing.

I am not one of them. `NULL` values are just fine for columns with no data. They are certainly the cheapest way to store "empty" columns - for disk space as well as performance (the main effect being smaller tables and indices):

- [Does not using NULL in PostgreSQL still use a NULL bitmap in the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008753/does-not-using-null-in-postgresql-still-use-a-null-bitmask-in-the-header/7383198#7383198)
- [Does setting "NOT NULL" on a column in postgresql increase performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222314/does-setting-not-null-on-a-column-in-postgresql-increase-performance?lq=1)
- [Do nullable columns occupy additional space in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145772/does-null-occupy-space-in-postgresql?lq=1)

Once you *understand* the nature of `NULL` values, there is no reason to avoid them. Postgres offers a variety of functions to deal with NULLs. [`colaesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL), [`nullif()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF), [`concat()`, `concat_ws()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html), ...

Generally, as far as **performance** is concerned, a **NOT NULL constraint** beats a **CHECK constraint** and both beat **triggers** by a log shot. But even simple triggers are cheap. The cost of a `NOT NULL` constraint is next to nothing. Also, all of these only affect write operations, but in most applications read operations dominate.

The most relevant impact on performance (sub-optimal indices and queries aside) therefore is the **size** of tables and indices or, more importantly, **the number of tuples per data page**. Bigger tuples lead to slower performance for most use cases. The number of data pages that have to be read to satisfy a query increases accordingly. Available cache memory is saturated earlier.

I don't have a benchmark ready, but it's best to test for your particular environment anyway. These are just simple rules of thumb. Reality is a lot more complex.

Comment: I do not want to run away from the _NULLability_ but i'd like to unify absence of data between NULL and EMPTY. My question is, in terms of performance, **it is best to use NULL and have a CHECK CONSTRAINT on EMPTY or store EMPTY and have a NOT NULL CHECK CONSTRAINT?** From your link, all interesting, stands out storing lightness of NULL compared to any other. **How that "NULL lightness" improve performance compared with CHECK constraint EMPTY values?** That's my explained question.