# Stack depth limit exceeded in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verificar_pagina_inicial_final()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
IF NEW.pg_inicial < NEW.pg_final THEN
 INSERT INTO artigos(id_artigo,id_editora,tipo_artigo,pg_inicial,pg_final)
VALUES(NEW.id_artigo,NEW.id_editora,NEW.tipo_artigo,NEW.pg_inicial,NEW.pg_final);
END IF;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER verifiar_paginas_novo_artigo
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON artigos
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE  verificar_pagina_inicial_final();
```

When I try to insert it returns me this:

```
INSERT INTO public.artigos(id_artigo, id_editora, tipo_artigo, pg_inicial, pg_final)
VALUES (30, 3, 'teste', 1, 2);
```

Returns:

> ```
> ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
> HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO artigos(id_artigo,id_editora,tipo_artigo,pg_inicial,pg_final)
> VALUES(NEW.id_artigo,NEW.id_editora,NEW.tipo_artigo,NEW.pg_inicial,NEW.pg_final)"
> PL/pgSQL function verificar_pagina_inicial_final() line 4 at SQL statement
> ```

Comment: It seems that your trigger and procedure form an infinite recursion. `ON INSERT` trigger calls SP that itself performs `INSERT` on the same table.

Comment: thanks for answering ... so when he inserts in the function he calls the trigger again? is there any way I can do this just once?

Answer (score 7):

Your trigger inserts the same row over and over again. There are various ways to prevent this. Like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER verifiar_paginas_novo_artigo
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON artigos
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() < 1)  -- !
EXECUTE FUNCTION verificar_pagina_inicial_final();
```

See:

- [How to prevent a PostgreSQL trigger from being fired by another trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/103661/3684)

`EXECUTE FUNCTION` requires Postgres 11. See:

- [Trigger function does not exist, but I am pretty sure it does](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/255319/3684)

**But** it seems you just want to disallow `pg_inicial >= pg_final`. You could do that with a `CHECK` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE artigos ADD CONSTRAINT pg_final_must_be_greater_than_pg_inicial
CHECK (pg_inicial < pg_final);
```

A `CHECK` constraint is simpler, faster, and more reliable. See:

- [Trigger vs. check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409952/trigger-vs-check-constraint/18411888#18411888)
- [How much cost check constraints in Postgres 9.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137811/how-much-cost-check-constraints-in-postgres-9-x/19141130#19141130)

Raises an exception when violated, of course, which typically is the way to go.
To do it silently, you are back to triggers. Just simpler:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verificar_pagina_inicial_final()
  RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF NEW.pg_inicial < NEW.pg_final THEN
      RETURN NEW;   -- proceed
   ELSE
      RETURN NULL;  -- skip insert / update
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

To proceed normally with an `INSERT` / `UPDATE`, a `BEFORE` trigger must `RETURN NEW;`. `RETURN NULL` cancels the row.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is just a test before an insertion as you do not modify the data, maybe

```
IF (NEW.pg_inicial < NEW.pg_final) THEN
      RETURN NEW;
ELSE
      RETURN NULL;
END IF;
```

p.s: I'll make a DB fiddle to check if this syntax is OK.
here is the fiddle, https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9iDx4bmJdk5rUzPrFdevAt/2 .

Edit2: Erwin Brandstetter's answer is complete, you should add a constraint instead of this trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are "Inserting" only new columns, the insert, in the trigger function, is completely unnecessary - that's what is going to be inserted anyway.  The question becomes what do you want then IF NEW.pg_inicial < NEW.pg_final" returns False. You have basically 3 options:

1. Do nothing, in which case just do not have a trigger at all.
2. Abort the complete insert statement. In this case create a check
   constraint and do not have a trigger at all. Alternately "Raise
   Exception" in the trigger, but that is not a good plan.
3. Silently ignore (skip) this particular row but otherwise continue
   see [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can
>       return null to signal the trigger manager to skip the rest of the
>       operation for this row (i.e., subsequent triggers are not fired, and
>       the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does not occur for this row).

In which implement the trigger function as follows:

```
create or replace 
function verificar_pagina_inicial_final()
  returns trigger 
  language plpgsql
as $$
begin
   if new.pg_inicial < new.pg_final 
   then
       return new;
   else 
       return null; 
   end if; 
end;
$$ ;
```